# Laravel Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I have this in web.php

```
Route::resource('urls', 'UrlController', ['except'=> ['index']]);
```

I have thie in URLController:

```
 public function create()
    {

        try{
            $url = new Url(["short_url" =>  '1ry23', 'original_url' =>  'http://goosssssssgle.com', 'created_at' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), 'clicks_count' => 0]);
            $url->save();
            return redirect('/');
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            return redirect('insert')->with('failed',"operation failed");
        }
        
    }
```

View:

```
  {{Form::model($url, array('route' => 'urls.create'))}}
```

And is throwing: Laravel Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException

I do not understand the reason.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... the form should be going to `urls.store` which stores the data ... the `create` route is for displaying the form to create the resource .... what you have in the `create` method of that Controller should be the `store` method

Comment: I just commented the whole code inside the "create" method and the same error is thrown.
Why is that¿?

Comment: Besides I do not understand what should be instead
{{Form::model($url, array('route' => 'urls.create'))}}
?

Comment: @lagbox may you give a help, thanks in advance.